# Не подключается шрифт через @font-face

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sass

Создаю веб-приложение на React'e и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу подключить шрифт через @font-face. Как это можно исправить помогите пожалуйста, внизу привёл код и скрины расположения файлов. Использую css препроцессоры, в данном случае [image: sass.]

```css
@font-face
    font-family: 'macherie'
    src: local("macherie"),
    src: url("../fonts/macherie.ttf"), format("truetype")
    font-weight: 700

*
margin: 0
padding: 0

h1
    font-family: macherie, sans-serif
    font-style: normal
    font-weight: 600
    font-size: clamp(55px,5.728800000000001vw,220px)
    line-height: 120%
```

Comment: Синтаксис src неправильный, запятые как попало стоят

Comment: А как правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покажите ошибку в браузере вкладку Network?
Если ругается на загрузку шрифта 404 (значит проблема в пути) если даже не открывается то проблема в синтаксисе sass.

Если подключаете `font-weight: 700` то и на `h1` должен быть `700` а не `600`

Пример как у меня в проекте подключается свой шрифт (с web версиями) правда там scss но легко переделать можно под sass:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пример sass:

в `app.sass` сверху добавляем `@import "fonts";`
Создаем файл: `_fonts.sass` обязательно с подчеркиванием и папку `_mixins` с файлом `_font-face.sass`

в файл `_fonts.sass` добавляем:

```
@import "_mixins/font-face"

+font-face("macherie", "../fonts/macherie", 700)
```

в файл `_mixins/_font-face.sass`

```
@mixin font-face($font-family, $file-path, $weight: normal, $style: normal )
@font-face
    font-family: $font-family
    font-weight: $weight
    font-style: $style
    font-display: swap
    src: url('#{$file-path}.ttf') format('truetype')
```

в файле `app.sass` для `h1`

```
h1
    font-family: macherie, sans-serif
    font-weight: 700
```